# Is passing the constructor's parameters as an instance of the class accepted?

Tags: c++, constructor

I came upon this case (simplified)
This compiles without any warnings concerning how it seems to cast the given parameter to an instance of the class B in class A's constructor

```
class B{
    public:
        B(int _x) { }
        virtual ~B() { }
};

class A{
    public:
        A(const B& source) { }
        virtual ~A() { }
};

int main(){
    new A(1);
    return 0;
}
```

#### 1. Is this considered good practice?

I have not seen any code in C++ that gives the constructor's parameters when asked for an instance/a const reference. Is it an unspoken rule?

#### 2. To what extent is this possible/allowed without and with warnings?

This does not work when the function prototype asks for a (not `const`) reference.

#### 3. When does the compiler think this is better than an overloaded function?

Compiling following example:

```
class B
{
    public:
        B(double _x = 0, double _y = 0) { }
        virtual ~B() { }
};

class A
{
    public:
        A(const B& source, int z = 0) {cout << "B class constructor";}
        A(double _x, double _y){cout << "primitive types";}
        virtual ~A() { }
};

int main()
{
    new A(1, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the warning (with certain compiler options):

```
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
note: candidate 1: A::A(double, double)
note: candidate 2: A::A(const B&, int)
```

(I understand that the compiler is conflicted with the int->double)

But when removing the `int z = 0` parameter from the `(const B&, int)` constructor the warning disappears (and still prints "`primitive types`")
Which is in my opinion much more ambiguous.

How is the ambiguity decided?

Comment: Have you read up in your C++ textbook on this?

Comment: 'I have not seen any code in C++ that gives the constructor's parameters when asked for an instance/a const reference.' This statement is meaningless. There is no code here that does this, and no syntax for 'gives the constructors parameters', or any meaning that I can see. What you are seeing here is just an ordinary typecast, made possible by the `const`.

Comment: About (1): There is nothing bad about it. Would you call `void foo(const std::string &s){}` `foo("123");` a bad practice? About (2): It doesn't work with non-const references because they can't bind to temporaries, and implicit conversion you have there produces a temporary. About (3): Look up [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). About the warning: it disappears because there are two arguments in `new A(1, 1)`, and you only have one constructor with two parameters.

Comment: @EJP: What the statement you quoted means is "I haven't seen calls that use a converting constructor to initialize a parameter.".  Not that this is true if you've seen much code.

Comment: @DavisHerring I know what is happening here thanks, and that's not what he said, and what he did say is meaningless. A large part of the problem here is the OP's extraordinary language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is this considered good practice?
>
> I have not seen any code in C++ that gives the constructor's parameters when asked for an instance/a const reference. Is it an unspoken rule?

'Gives the constructor's parameters' is meaningless. What is happening here is that a `const B` object is being constructed from a `double` via the constructor you provided for the purpose. Nothing more mysterious than that. It is in fact a simple typecasting operation, and a C++ compiler will always take into account a single-step typecast if it is available when passing a parameter or return value.

> 2. To what extent is this possible/allowed without and with warnings?

To the extent that it is possible in a single step without ambiguity.

> This does not work when the function prototype asks for a (not const) reference.

That's because the compiler won't construct a non-const temporary object, by the rules of C++.

> 3. When does the compiler think this is better than an overloaded function?
>      ... which in my option is much more ambiguous

It isn't.

> How is the ambiguity resolved?

There is no ambiguity to resolve. There is no rule in C++ that says it should attempt to construct a single `const B` object out of two or more parameters.